# python-requests broken after upgrade from 0.12.1 to 2.7.0

Tags: python, authentication, post, python-requests

1. **Was** On kali 1:
   Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2. **Version of requests module is 0.12.1**
2. **Now** On kali 2:
   Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar 1 2015, 12:57:24) [GCC 4.9.2] on linux2. **Version of requests module is 2.7.0**

There was easy api_query for cryptsy:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import time
import urllib

def api_query( method, req = {}):
        # API settings
        key = API_KEY # your API-key
        secret = API_SECRET # your Secret-key
        req['method'] = method
        req['nonce'] = int( time.time() )
        # generate the POST data string
        post_data = urllib.urlencode( req )
        sign = hmac.new( secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512)
        # generate the extra headers
        headers = { 'Sign': sign.hexdigest(), 'Key': key }
        url = 'https://api.cryptsy.com/api'
        print 'post_data = ' + post_data
        print 'headers = ' + str( headers )
        r = requests.post( url, data=post_data, headers = headers )
        print r
        for i in  r.__dict__:
                print ''
                print i, r.__dict__[i]
        return r.text
```

It works on kali 1, but kali 2 - NOT.

```
>>> print api_query("getinfo")
{"success":"0","error":"Unable to Authorize Request - Check Your Post Data"}
```

For the first time, I've launched kali 1 in qemu and started to compare two similar codes. I've to setted `nonce` to one number and tested the difference between two `post_datas`. Everything was equal. Even `Sign(kali1) == Sign(kali2)`.

I'm changing address from api.cryptsy.com to 127.0.0.1. And I can see, that:

- 0.12.1 send `Data` as one encoded string. - Good.
- 2.7.0 converted string back to `HTML Form URL Encoded`.

Comment: have you checked the requests changelogs?

Comment: `post_data = urllib.urlencode( req )` looks suspicious for me. I don't think you need to to encode post data in new version.

Comment: @yaroslav-admin you are right. Thank you. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yaroslav Admin mentioned, new version of requests need no urlencode anymore. Otherwise, its convert this `html-request`-like string, like `?a=b&c=1&d=hello` backward to dictionary-like payload, which is wrong on the server side.

That is why, need to improve only one string in my cryptsy's api_query example:

```
r = requests.post( url, data = post_data, headers = headers )
```

to

```
r = requests.post( url, data = req, headers = headers )
```

Everything else is correct.